# MS Graph API: invalid authentication token

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to query an Outlook/O365 mailbox for messages. I [registered my app](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) in the Azure portal and received the necessary information to query the API. The app has the `Mail.Read` permission. (I don't have access to the Azure portal, I was told it was set up this way.) When I get my token from the OAuth endpoint, however, it doesn't work in any subsequent calls. I'm using Python's requests module for testing right now.

Why is this call failing? It seems like I'm passing all of the correct information but I'm clearly missing something.

I'm getting the token by performing a `POST` on:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/my.domain/oauth2/token
```

I pass the necessary parameters:

```
data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_id': CLIENTID, 'client_secret': SECRET, 'resource': APPURI}
```

and I get a response like this:

```
{
    'resource': 'APPURI',
    'expires_in': '3599',
    'ext_expires_in': '3600',
    'access_token': 'TOKENHERE',
    'expires_on': '1466179206',
    'not_before': '1466175306',
    'token_type': 'Bearer'
}
```

I try to use that token, however, and it doesn't work for anything I call. I'm passing it as a header:

```
h = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + TOKEN}
```

I'm calling this URL:

```
url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/my.email.address@example.com/messages'
```

Specifically, I use this:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=h)
```

The response is a 401:

```
{
    'error': {
        'innerError': {
            'date': '2016-06-17T15:06:30',
            'request-id': '[I assume this should be removed for privacy]'
         },
         'code': 'InvalidAuthenticationToken',
         'message': 'Access token validation failure.'
     }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

in your login request, the resource parameter should be https://graph.microsoft.com

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be the case, that tokens issued from the v1 endpoint aren't valid for atleast some requests with MS Graph API.

Instead try to get the token form the v2 endpoint by calling `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`.

In case you are working with oidc discovery documents, you'll find the one for v2 at `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are an using [Client Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds), you cannot access the messages another account's mailbox. Make sure that `my.email.address@example.com` is the same account you are authenticated with and that this address is also the userPrincipalName for the account.

You can also use a simplified URI for requesting your messages and bypassing determining the account's `userPrincipalName` by using `/me`. In this case the `GET` request would be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`

Comment: I'm trying to set up a task on my web app that will periodically check a specific mailbox for new emails and process attachments on them. Sounds like I'm going about it the wrong way then.

Comment: This will work but you'll need to either get a token using that mailbox's credentials or use an account with administrative privileges.

Comment: Hope it's okay to piggyback off of this. We can't figure out where to generate the credentials under the account; can't log into the portal because it's not an administrator account. Where would we do that?

Comment: The app information created in the [URL provided in the other answer](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) by Xiaomin returns this from the oauth endpoint: `Application 'IDHERE' is not supported for this API version.` Must not be the correct way to do it.

Comment: If you're registering at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com then make sure you are also using the [v2 Endpoint](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/). For classic Azure AD integration (aka v1) you need to register within your Azure AD instance and use the ID and secret from there.

Comment: Note that switching to v2 will not get around the Admin requirement for other user mailboxes.

Comment: Hmm... we're trying to use the classic integration, but can't find a way to register it under a specific user. The apps appear to be created globally. The account can't log into the portal because it isn't an administrator. The person who created the credentials originally _is_ an administrator but they still don't work.

Comment: You don't register an app to a specific user. You register an app to Azure AD and the actual user authenticates using OAUTH. 

OAUTH has 3 components - the "User" with a User ID, the "App" with an App ID, and a "Provider" which authenticates both the "User" (via the user's credentials) and the "App" (via the app's registration ID). 

In order to access remote mailboxes the "User" must be an Admin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114972/discussion-between-vaindil-and-marc-lafleur-msft).

Comment: I am not able to get data from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`
I have authenticated with the same mail id in each place **Error:**
`{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token is empty.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-11-01T13:58:00",
            "request-id": "74ed3c30-bd7b-4642-a9d0-e3a7c89c0d4e",
            "client-request-id": "74ed3c30-bd7b-4642-a9d0-e3a7c89c0d4e"
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to register app from here "https://apps.dev.microsoft.com" instead of from Azure Portal.

Comment: This won't be of help. The page says - "Application registrations portal has been deprecated for registering and managing converged applications since May 2019 and this functionality will be removed starting September 2019. We recommend that you manage your existing applications and register new applications by using the App registrations (now Generally Available) experience in the Azure portal."

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that even if MS's Azure documentation does not specify the need for listing the resource, I could never get to work without listing the resource.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds.

There is a supplementary document specifiy to two-legged Auth for MS Graph that actually uses the 'resource' in the example.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_only

Happy hunting!

Comment: How to specify more than one resource there ?