# MS Graph API authentication token does not return scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I'm pretty confused as to how to use the MS Graph API.

I'm trying to log a server side daemon (webapp) into Azure, and then access OneDrive within an Office 365 instance.

(1) I created an app Azure portal with Web app /API type. Then i gave it access inside the Azure portal to all the permissions I could give it access to.
(2) Then I went into the MS application console (apps.dev.microsoft.com) and gave it access over there also. Why are there two sets of permissions?
(3) Also created a secret key and password.
(4) This is what I do (a) send request to get token with key/password, (b) use token to talk to the graph endpoint.

First it would not work, but then i gave the app an admin 'consent' and it seemed like it worked.

The problem is, as you can see below, there is simply no scope on the token. All the permissions added everywhere seem to not provided a scope?

[Missing scope in token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDsuK.png)

What is weirder is I try to get the /drives in O365, the below resposne comes back. So clearly there are some drives, but the drives seem to have no owner as far as I can tell, and are not personal drives or sharepoint drives as far as I can tell.

[mystery drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvowp.png)

Notes:
(a) I think the problem is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885476/ms-graph-api-invalid-authentication-token)
(b) Why do I need to do the 'consent' thing? I don't want users to be redirected, I just want my server side app to be able to save files/folders to a OneDrive.

Any ideas? This seems like a pretty simple use case, but ms graph is acting quite strange.

Can someone tell me if the process is correct, i.e. (a) get token, (b) use token. Is there another magic step here with 'consent', and if so where is it documented?

Comment: You need to decode the access token. Use a site like this: http://calebb.net/, and paste the raw access token. Then you should be able to see the claims

Comment: that worked exactly. why they would not document something like that obviously is beyond me. there is no where which says, the token is a jwt, use as you wish.

Comment: I'll write up a proper answer to this. everything seems to be working as expected now. I'm still a bit confused as to what the drive info comming back is, but it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different things here which add to the confusion, but the actual answer is simple.

(1) Scope token: As mentioned by [Shawn Tabrizi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396977/shawn-tabrizi), the access_token itself contains the scope information. A number of the documentation sites from MS show a distict scope field within the returned token. This is (apparently - could not find official documentation) no longer the case.
(2) To work out whether you have given the correct scopes to the token, simple copy your access_token into a JWT converter, such as [calebb.net](http://calebb.net/). Also from [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396977/shawn-tabrizi).

(3) A lot of the confusion is about where and how to give the correct permissions. 
(a) In the Azure portal, go to Azure Active Directory and add a new webapp. My use case was specifically a server side JS app. The first line in the App Registrations panel, after an 'Add' and 'Endpoint' buttons says 'To view and manage your registrations for converged applications, please visit the Microsoft Application Console.' Ignore this. 
(b) If you click on it, it will take you to MS's app registration service, which adds a whole heap of confusion. Simply stick to the normal Azure portal (the new fancy one), it will save you grief.
(c) There are several id's, and little info about what you should use. Assuming your use case is working with MS Graph API, you need 3 things.

- tenantID: this is found by clicking on the endpoints button and using the endpoint related to the OAuth token. It looks like 8alphanumric-4aphanumeric-4aphanumeric-4aphanumeric-12alphanumric for me.
- client id: This is your Application Id. So you have a Display Name (app name), Application id (8-4-4-4-12 alphanumric) [this is the client id you need], Application Type (Web app/API for me) and Object id (8-4-4-4-12 alphanumric) [ignore this]
- client secret: this was non obvious. Click on All settings. then go to keys. here you will make up a key. give it any name (does not matter), set the duration to what you need. It will give you a key when you click save. This is your client secret. No idea what happens if you create more than 1. Appreciate the sentiment that you can have multiple keys, but my use case did not need me to investigate.

(d) Permissions: The documentation shows some stuff about putting permissions into the app centre, and other stuff. Stack overflow talks about 'consent' and 'admin permissions'. Ignore most of this.

(e) Your app will already have a permission for Windows Azure Active Directory. There are 2 kinds of permissions, delegated and application. Delegated means (i think) an workflow where the user logs in as a separate step into their `<whatever>` account which happens to use AD authentication.

(f) For the server side app which was my use case, you will need only application permissions. Add whatever you need.

(g) Now add an API in permissions, MS Graph in this case. Again, my use case meant I only needed application permissions.

(h) What about consent? Once you have added permissions, and clicked save, click on the 'Grant Permissions' button next to 'Add'. You only have to do this after changes. This is the explicit step of an Admin authorising the application with consent for all the permissions it needs.

(i) Once you are done with Required Permissions, got to Properties. It makes up an App Id URI, which you need to click save for.

After all this stuff (once only), the app should work fine. Parse the access_token so see if you have all the correct permissions. Basic flow is a to get a token, and use the token to do whatever.

Note that half the stuff for application flow in graph is dodgy (at the moment). The capabilities are very good, but a lot of the routes don't work for app only access, but work for user (delegated) access. Read known issues to see what is at where. I've had luck with users and shared mailboxes being accessed by the app. Groups is pretty badly supported for webapp access at the moment (March 1, 2017).